# Simply stretching an image on any device with Delphi and Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm working on a quite simple Delphi app using Firemonkey. My customer has a huge number of different devices and screen sizes. For a technical image, I use an TImage component (client aligned) and assigned a number of JPGs to the "MultiResBitmap" property. Surprisingly, it does not look good on any device. There are white edges on every side. Coming from VCL, I'm just searching for a "Stretch" property as it is no problem in that case if the aspect ratio of the image is not 100% correct. What other component can I use? Or is there a "Stretch" like property?

[EDIT0] Thanks to Erik I found the "Stretch" value on the WrapMode property. Behaviour changed a bit, but the problem stays the same.

[White edges on the left and right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TZag.png)

[EDIT1] Here is he code of the DFM file, excluding image data of course.

```
         object imgSearchBackground: TImage
            MultiResBitmap.Height = 1143
            MultiResBitmap.Width = 841
            MultiResBitmap = <
              item
                Width = 841
                Height = 1143
                PNG = {....}
                FileName = 'f:\projects\image0.jpg'
              end>
            Align = Client
            Size.Width = 779.000000000000000000
            Size.Height = 308.000000000000000000
            Size.PlatformDefault = False
            WrapMode = Stretch
          end
```

Comment: As I haven't seen what you describe, I made a test and indeed, I still can not reproduce. Please edit your question to include the code you use, the setup of your `TImage` and show the code that loads the file(s). Perhaps also a picture of the bad result you see.

Comment: I don't use any code, the images within the MultiResBitmap property are assigned at designtime. The picture shows the bad result on Windows, it is nearly the same on Android and iOS, the white edges are more on the side or on the top depending on the device.

Comment: I did not only ask for the code you use, I also asked for *the setup of your TImage*. That means the properties and their values that you have setup at design time. The easiest way to post those, is to copy the relevant section from the `.fmx` file, alternatively selecting "View as text" from the popup menu in design view. However, as you have the images already loaded at design time, please remove the hugh `MultiResBitmap` part before posting.

Answer (score 2):

You will find the "Stretch" (amongst other options) equivalent under the `WrapMode` property of FMX's `TImage`.

See [FMX.Objects.TImage.WrapMode](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FMX.Objects.TImage.WrapMode)